# How to hide UITextField border?

Tags: xcode, uikit, uitextview, border

I have a UITextField and I am trying to make the UITextField border invisible so that the background and UITextField would have the same color and there would be a seamless look. But the problem is I also use a placeholder and there is a border that I cannot remove. I already tried:

```
textOption.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textOption.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

It didn't work. Would you please help me on that? I still can see the border of the UITextField. fyi: The UITextView that I use doesn't have this issue => There is no placeholder in UITextViews.

Comment: what about textOption.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; ...

Answer (score 106):

If you want to remove the textfield border you can do it directly with interface builder:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me! Could it also be something else as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Just use this..

```
textOption.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
[textOption setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 19):

Swift 4 and 5 :

```
yourTextfield.borderStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 14):

In Swift this worked for me :

```
 passwordTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Interface Builder or Storyboard, you can select the textField, go on the Attributes inspector's tab, under the option Border Style you have 4 styles to chose from, the first one is without border.

If doing it in code, this should work

```
textOption.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
[textOption setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to just set border style None

```
 textFieldName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *tfText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 200, 200, 30)];
    tfText.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.9 blue:0.5 alpha:0.3];       
    tfText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    // Border Style None
    [tfText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    [self.view addSubview:tfText];
    [tfText release];
```