# how to customize uitextfield appearance

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to customize the UItextbox

I want to get rid of the rounded corners and just keep a bottom line.

If I could have a my own color for the bottom line then it'd be good 
[image]

But I am unable to find a way to do this

Comment: Use this to hide borders, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29515827/1891327, and then draw border on one side using this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17609532/1891327

Comment: Here's a swift way to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41291113/4475605

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField border for bottom side only in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800963/uitextfield-border-for-bottom-side-only-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question objectively, you need to create a new class extending UITextField, in this way you will define the behaviour what you want. If you do not know how to start I suggest you get some custom UITextField as an example from GITHUB, there are so many there. Observe how to custom and draw things inside the control. When you have an extended UITextFiled class, select the control on your XIB or storyboard and you need just set the base class of control in XCODE as shown in the picture below. I hope it helps you.

[image]

Comment: I have written a tutorial to explain how to add inner shadow inside a UITextField at https://medium.com/@andersongusmao/adding-inner-shadow-on-uiinputtext-db8c34e45d6